# Limit http calls from a factory service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-factory

I'm using a `factory` service to fetch some data using the `$http` service. The problem here, I dont want to make a `http` request each time, I want to save this data somewhere and get a local copy of it when needed. To that end I thought creating an array inside that `factory` and assign the loaded data to it on the first call, and then just return it when required, instead of loading it again from the server. In my case, it the `http` service is fired every time. How can I fix this? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027832/angular-best-practice-for-retrieving-data-from-a-factory-method) but that does not answer my question.

This is my `factory`:

```
angular.module("app").factory("getDataService", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var usersArray = [];
    if (usersArray.length === 0) {
        return {
            getJsonData: function () {
                return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/eznv3')
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        usersArray = data;
                        return data;
                    })
                    .error(function (error, status, headers, config) {
                    });
            }
        }
    }else{
        return usersArray;
    }
}]);
```

And this is the `controller` that uses this service:

```
angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "getDataService", function ($scope, getDataService) {

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            getDataService.getJsonData().then(function (data) {
                $scope.users = data.data;
            });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: What @ankit posted is correct. Other way is store the data in HTML sessionStorage on the first call & set isCacheFlag = true. Before hitting the server you can check if the flag is false then hit the server else serve the response from Session Or Local storoage

Comment: Thank you for complement !! By the way, we make our own code too, but we have to manage it for each and every request we make, if we wish to cache response of all get requests. But {cache: true} is far better that the code complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to cache the response of `$http.get` manually, angularJS itself provides a way to cache the response. Try below code in your getJsonData function of your factory:

```
getJsonData: function () {
    return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/eznv3', {cache: true})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          return data;
     })
     .error(function (error, status, headers, config) {
     });
}
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Read the above document. You will find configurations from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Local Storage** for it, one of the best and easiest ways.

**`LocalStorage.setItem('usersArray',data);`** sets the data in the local storage.

**`LocalStorage.getItem('usersArray');`** retrieves the data from local storage.

Here is the change of your factory,

```
angular.module("app").factory("getDataService", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var usersArray = LocalStorage.getItem('usersArray');
    if (usersArray.length === 0) {
        return {
            getJsonData: function () {
                return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/eznv3', {cache: true})
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        usersArray = data;
                        LocalStorage.setItem('usersArray',data);
                        return data;
                    })
                    .error(function (error, status, headers, config) {
                    });
            }
        }
    }else{
        return LocalStorage.getItem('usersArray');
    }
}]);
```

Your controller,

```
angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "getDataService", function ($scope, getDataService) {

    var x = [];

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        if (x.length == 0) {
            getDataService.getJsonData().then(function (data) {
                x = data.data;
                $scope.users = x;
            });
        }else{
            console.log("local copy of data exists");
        }
    });
}]);
```

**Advantages of localstorage:**

- With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.
- Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Comment: Don't you think he needs to check if the local storage is null or not. If its null make an ajax call else serve the data from local storage

Comment: I never tried that option, so though everyone is adding that, I didn't add because I don;t know if it was correct. as you said that, I am going to add now. thnx for that.

Answer (score 1):

Few days back, i got same kind of requirement and following is code of module i had created for same...

```
'use strict';
(function() {
    angular.module('httpService', []).service("api", ["$http", "dbService", function($http, dbService) {
        /**
         * <Pankaj Badukale>
         * ()
         * request.url      => Url to request 
         * request.method   => request method
         * request.data     => request data
         * request.mask     => This is custom object for out use
         *
         * @return ()
         */
        return function (request) {
            var url         = (request != undefined && request.url != undefined) ? request.url : "./";
            var method      = (request != undefined && request.method != undefined) ? request.method : "GET";
            var rData       = (request != undefined && request.data != undefined) ? request.data : {};
            /**
             * mask is CUSTOME object we add to request object
             * Which is useful for keep track of each request as well interceptor execute
             * 
             * IT HAS
             *  {
             *      save        : true, //tell that save request response in session
             *      fetch       : true, //check local data first,
             *      fetchSource : tell about perticular source of data DEFAULT WILL BE sessionStorage
             *                    OPTIONS are session and local
             *  } strucutre FOR NOW may be it will better or enhance in future
             *
             * message property to set message in alert
             * doExecute tell wheather you want to execute maskMan code for this request
             *
             * while saving and fetching data from local it uses URL of request as key
             * maskMan is a factory which iterate your error response object and we can add different behaviours for maskMan
             */
            var mask        = {};

            if(request != undefined && request.mask != undefined) {
                mask = request.mask;
            }

            return dbService.http(request).then(function(data) {
                console.log("Data fetched from local "+ request.url);
                return data;
            }, function(err) {
                return $http({
                    url: url,
                    method: method,
                    data: rData,
                    mask: mask,
                    header:{
                            'content-type':'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                },function(error) {
                    return error;
                });
            });
        };
    }]).service('customHttpInterceptor', ["$q", "maskMan", function($q, maskMan) {
        return {
            //before send request to server
            request: function(config) {                 
                    return config;
            },
            //if any found in request object
            requestError: function(rejection) {
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            //on response come to web app
            response: function(response) {              
                maskMan.responseIterator(response);
                //you to return any thing as response from here
                return response;
            },
            //if there is error in response`
            responseError: function(rejection) {                
                maskMan.statusIterator(rejection);              
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]).factory("maskMan", ["dbService", function(dbService) {
        return {
            /**
             * statusIterator
             * Iterate response object on error comes
             */
            statusIterator: function(rejection) {
                if( rejection.config.mask.doExecute == true) {
                    switch(rejection.status) {
                        case 404: this.notFound(rejection);
                            break;
                        default: this.dontKnow(rejection);
                    }   
                }
            },
            /**
             * notFound
             * Function to defined logic for 404 error code scenario's
             * Here we can defined generic as well specific request object conditions also
             */
            notFound: function(rejection) {
                var errMsg = rejection.config.mask.message || "Something wrong";

                alert(errMsg);

                rejection.stopExecute = true;//stop further execute of code flag
            },
            /**
             * dontKnow
             * For every error response this method goingt to envoke by default
             */
            dontKnow: function(maskObject) {
                console.log("Don't know what to do for "+maskObject.config.url);
            },
            /**
             * responseIterator
             * Define logic to do after response come to browser
             * 
             * @params JSON resp
             */
            responseIterator: function(resp) {
                //Logic to save data of response in session storage with mask command save
                if( resp.config.mask !== undefined && resp.config.mask.save === true ) {
                    var sdata   = JSON.stringify(resp.data);
                    var skey    = resp.config.url;

                    dbService.sinsert(skey, sdata);
                }//END
            }
        };
    }]).service("dbService", ["$q", function($q) {
        /**
         * http
         * Custom mirror promise to handle local storage options with http
         * 
         * @params JSON request
         */
        this.http = function(request) {
            var self = this;
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                if( request.mask != undefined && request.mask.fetch === true ) {
                    var data = null;

                    if( request.mask.fetchSource == undefined || request.mask.fetchSource == "session") {//go for default sessionStorage
                        data = JSON.parse(self.sget(request.url));
                    } else if( request.mask.fetchSource == "local" ) {
                        data = JSON.parse(self.get(request.url));
                    } else {
                        reject( "Fetch source is not defined." );
                    }

                    if( data != undefined && data != null ) {
                        resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        reject("Data not saved in local "+request.url);
                    }
                } else {
                    reject("Data not saved in local "+request.url);
                }
            });
        }

        /** 
          * Add/Override data to local storage
          *
          * @params String key
          * @params Array/Json data
          * @params Function callback
          * 
          * @return Boolean/Function
          */
        this.insert =  function(key, data, callback) {          
            localStorage.setItem(key, data);

            if( callback != undefined ) {
                callback();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

         /** 
           * Update data of local storage
           * This function generally used to data which is already exist and need to update
           * 
           * @params String key
           * @params Array/Json data
           * @params Function callback
           * 
           * @return Boolean/Function
           */
        this.update = function(key, data, callback) {
            var self = this;
            self.view(key, function(localData) {//callback function
                if( localData != undefined && localData != null ) {
                    //already some data exist on this key So need to update it
                    data = localData.push(data);
                }
                //just handover to insert
                if( callback !== undefined ) {
                    self.insert(key, data, callback);
                } else {
                    return self.insert(key, data);
                }
            });         
        }

         /**
           * Remove data from local storage on basis of key
           * 
           * @params String key
           * @return Boolean
           */
        this.remove = function(key, callback) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);

                if( callback !== undefined ) {
                    callback();
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        }

        /**
          * Get key data of local storage
          * @param String key
          * 
          * @return Array data WHEN all data    OR
          * @return String data WHEN key value
          */
        this.get = function(key, callback) {
            var key = key || "";
            var data = [];

            if( key == "" ) {
                //get all data
                for(var i in localStorage) {
                    data.push(JSON.parse(localStorage[i]));
                }
            } else {
                //get one key data
                data = localStorage.getItem(key);
            }

            if(callback != undefined) {
                callback(data);
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }

        /** 
          * sinsert
          * Add/Override data to session storage
          *
          * @params String key
          * @params Array/Json data
          * @params Function callback
          * 
          * @return Boolean/Function
          */
        this.sinsert =  function(key, data, callback) {
            var key = this.encode(key);

            sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);

            if( callback != undefined ) {
                callback();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

         /** 
           * supdate
           * Update data of session storage
           * This function generally used to data which is already exist and need to update
           * 
           * @params String key
           * @params Array/Json data
           * @params Function callback
           * 
           * @return Boolean/Function
           */
        this.supdate = function(key, data, callback) {
            var self = this;
            self.view(key, function(localData) {//callback function
                if( localData != undefined && localData != null ) {
                    //already some data exist on this key So need to update it
                    data = localData.push(data);
                }
                //just handover to insert
                if( callback !== undefined ) {
                    self.insert(key, data, callback);
                } else {
                    return self.insert(key, data);
                }
            });         
        }

         /**
           * sremove
           * Remove data from session storage on basis of key
           * 
           * @params String key
           * @return Boolean
           */
        this.sremove = function(key, callback) {
                var key = this.encode(key);

                sessionStorage.removeItem(key);

                if( callback !== undefined ) {
                    callback();
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        }

        /**
          * get
          * Get key data of session storage
          * @param String key
          * 
          * @return Array data WHEN all data    OR
          * @return String data WHEN key value
          */
        this.sget = function(key, callback) {
            var key = key || "";
            var data = [];

            if( key == "" ) {
                //get all data
                for(var i in sessionStorage) {
                    data.push(JSON.parse(sessionStorage[i]));
                }
            } else {
                //get one key data
                key = this.encode(key);

                data = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
            }

            if(callback != undefined) {
                callback(data);
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }

        /**
          * encode
          * encode give string using javascript
          *
          * @param String str
          * @return String
          */        
        this.encode = function(str) {
            return btoa(str);
        }

        /**
          * decode
          * decode give string using javascript
          *
          * @param String str
          * @return String
          */                
        this.decode = function(str) {
            return atob(str);
        }

        return this;

    }]).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('customHttpInterceptor');
    }]);
})();
```

How to use it::

Include this module in you project....

Then use "httpService" always for http requests all for API calls...

We need to pass config object to this service tell about API call and what should do with it....You can find details about config in code itself...

So how to use in controller..

```
module.controller('nameofController', ['httpService', function(httpService)  {
    httpService({
        url: 'Your API url',
        method: 'GET',
        mask: {
                  save        : true, //tell that save request response in session
                  fetch       : true, //check local data first before next fetch,
                  fetchSource : tell about perticular source of data DEFAULT WILL BE sessionStorage OPTIONS are session and local
             }
    }).then(function(data) {
        // promise is all same as $http
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Hope this will help... You can go with very simple solution as well to just mark

> `{cache: true}`

...
But this solution is completely customized and under all controls

Original code which has used in production is at [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pankajbadukale/ee83297f8c8b33fcbd62/raw/0391a86d9ea2f5c4b7d699db5bde055e760a1efc/angular%2520http%2520storage%2520lang%2520mng)